# junit4 assert methods

Tags: junit4

hello I've write a junit test with eclipse , to check the Gui component status ,I use assert : textfield.assert("expected message") i'm searching how to get the error message printed by assert the message saying that the expected text doesn't match th typed text is printed in the eclipse console I like to get this message to generate a report is there an easy mean, my be a junit method ?

Comment: Could you try to be a little more specific? To use asserts you need to write a test in which you will likely use `AssertEquals` or `AssertTrue` methods. I don't recall `assert` method in JUnit.

Comment: we can use :
object.assertselected(); how to redirect the output message

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
AssertEquals("The value of A is not equal to the value of B", a, b);
```

The error message should be printed to the console when you run the above.

If **AssertEquals** does not meet your needs, you can use **AssertTrue**, or any of the other methods in the [JUnit API](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html).

Comment: thanks, but my aim is to get the message printed in the console and print it in a created file

Comment: Do you only want your JUnit output printed to a file, or all your console output?

Because if what you're looking for is the former, you can just redirect your foo.class output, by running "javac foo > foo.log" from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add your own JUnit [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html).